# Creating new folders relative to my current working directory

Tags: python-3.x, filepath

How can I use Python to create new folders relative to my current working directory?

For example, my path is C:/Documents/Code with no folders within and just has my Python file. How do I store some data within C:/Documents/Code/Data without hard coding the absolute path?

This is what I've been trying:

```
path = "/Data/file.txt"
file = open(path, "w")
```

This gives me the error of "No such file or directory".

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the path with a single dot `.`, which denotes your current working directory:

```
path = "./Data/file.txt"
#       ^
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gave me the exact same error as before.